# Keyboard navigation: anchor tag not redirecting

Tags: accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I have an Angular project in which I would like to add a "Skip to main content" link to redirect to the main section page when navigating via the keyboard. The piece of code is:

```
<a href="#main" class="skip-main"> Skip to main content</a>
```

However it's not working with the keyboard. When I click with the mouse, then it works as expected. I've tried adding role="button" and tabindex="0" but no success so far.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How are you activating it with the keyboard? Links can only be activated with Enter.